# How to do unit testing on inline styling of a component in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a function named as `BsButtons` and inside that I have Button which has an inline styling. I am trying to write a unit test to check whether the particular Button has a particular style or not.

**BsButtons.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
export const BsButtons = (props) => {
     const { buttonstyle } = props || {}; 
    return(
        <div>
            <Button style={{...buttonstyle,backgroundColor:'#7B4259', boxShadow:'0 3px 0px rgba(123, 66, 89, 0.15)',borderRadius:20, fontWeight:200}} {...props} />
        </div>
    );};
```

**BsButton.test.js**

```
import React from 'react' ;
import { renderer, create } from 'react-test-renderer' ;
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import BsButtons from '../../src/components/ButtonComponents/BsButtons';
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const tree = create(<BsButtons/>).toJSON();
it('Should have Background color as #7B4259', () => {
        expect(tree.find(Button)).to.have.style('backgroundColor','#7B4259')
    });
```

I'm getting an error that `tree.find is not a function`.

Answer (score 0):

`.find` works on the current wrapper. You're trying to use `.find()` on the test renderer instance that's why you are getting error as `tree.find is not a function`. First get the wrapper instance of your component and then try to find the style property.

Try this way:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

let wrapper = shallow(<BsButtons/>);
it('Should have Background color as #7B4259', () => {
  expect(wrapper.find(Button)).to.have.style('backgroundColor','#7B4259');
});
```

Comment: Still I'm getting error as "Cannot read property 'have' of undefined". I also tried with `expect(tree.find(Button)).toHaveStyle(`backgroundColor : #7B4259`)` but still not working.